# How to query sub work items in TFS2010 using .NET

Tags: .net

I created a task in TFS2010 and then created four tasks as child to the first task.
I want to get all tasks that are child of given task in .NET, any idea what the query will be or how to code that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can query sub task

```
public void GetSubWorkItems()
{
    var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://TFS:8080/TFS/DefaultCollection"));
    var workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

    var wiqlQuery = String.Format(@"Select [State], [Title] From WorkItemLinks Where ([Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task') Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"); ;

    var query = new Query(workItemStore, wiqlQuery);

    var workItems = query.RunLinkQuery();

    foreach (WorkItemLinkInfo workItemlink in workItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(workItemlink.SourceId);
    }
}
```

Thanks

M.Radwan

Comment: I don't know why the code didn't arranged it was arranged in the preview I try to edit and fix this but still the same sorry for that

Comment: Thanks Radwan,
That code spits out all the tasks, but What I want is

`code`
if workitem.workitemLinks.count > 1 then
GetSubWorkItems(TaskID)
End IF
`code`

Also, I got something working but the following code uses the hard code value for parent workitem (5 in the example below)

`code`
If workItemlink.SourceId = 5 Then litContent.Text += "SourceID=" & workItemlink.SourceId.ToString() & " - TaskID=" & workItemlink.TargetId.ToString() & " Title: " & wi.Title & " AssignedTo: " & wi.Fields("Assigned To").Value & "<br / >"
`code`